# How to display errors on laravel 4?

Tags: debugging, laravel, error-reporting, laravel-4

I'm trying to create an app on Laravel 4 beta but I can't debug it because it doesn't show any error, `display_errors` is on, `error_reporting` is `E_ALL` and `debug => true` (`config/app.php`). When I try to do an error on `public/index.php` it shows a parse error, but when I do it on the router it just shows a blank page (White screen of death). How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running on a local server environment? As far as I know, Laravel still checks to see if `local` or `.dev` appear in the URL before turning it into a local debug environment.

Comment: Oh, and what kind of error/exception are you throwing? Could you share that piece of code with us?

Comment: Also see: http://four.laravel.com/docs/configuration

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, only that I get a generic 500 server error instead of screen of death. Error reporting works fine out of L4

Comment: @Matanya - have you looked at your server logs to see WHAT the error 500 actually is? It could be any number of things...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*@Matanya* - have you looked at your server logs to see WHAT the error 500 actually is? It could be any number of things

*@Aladin* - white screen of death (WSOD) can be diagnosed in three ways with Laravel 4.

**Option 1:** Go to your Laravel logs (app/storage/logs) and see if the error is contained in there.

**Option 2:** Go to you PHP server logs, and look for the PHP error that is causing the WSOD

**Option 3:** Good old debugging skills - add a die('hello') command at the start of your routes file - then keep moving it deeper and deeper into your application until you no longer see the 'hello' message. Using this you will be able to narrow down the line that is causing your WSOD and fix the problem.

Comment: I forgot to set the permissions on the app/storage folder even though the laravel intro states that clearly. Thanks!

Comment: I keep seeing the WOSD with die('hello') in the first line of routes.php.. :(

Comment: I've added a "files" statement to composer.json. 
This was the error... I  still don't know what a I did wrong, but found the error.

Answer (score 38):

I had a problem with the white screen after installing a new laravel instance. I couldn't find anything in the logs because (eventually I found out) that the reason for the white screen was that app/storage wasn't writable.

In order to get an error message on the screen I added the following to the public/index.php

```
try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

After that it was easy to solve the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was linked here from: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/500-internal-server-error-after-install-laravel-bog

Answer (score 22):

Go to
app/config/app.php

and 
set 'debug' => true,

Answer (score 3):

Following the good advice by @The Shift Exchange I looked at the error_log and indeed managed to solve to problem. it was simply a permissions issue:

```
Tue Feb 26 11:22:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/app/start/../storage/logs/log-apache2handler-2013-02-26.txt" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:71\nStack trace:\n#0 /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(77): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(217): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(281): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(ErrorException), Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Monolog\\Logger->addError(Object(ErrorException))\n#5 /Users/matanya/Sites/in in /Users/matanya/Sites/indgo/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 71
```

Once I used `chmod` to apply less stringent permissions, all went back to normal.

However, I'm not sure that it answers the OP's question, as he was getting a blank screen rather than a server error.

Comment: glad it helped. I've posted an answer with some other tips

Answer (score 2):

Inside config folder open `app.php`

Change

```
'debug' => false,
```

to

```
'debug' => true,
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to @cw24's answer  •  as of Laravel `5.4` you would instead have the following amendment in `public/index.php`

```
try {
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

And in my case, I had forgotten to fire up MySQL.
Which, by the way, is usually `mysql.server start` in Terminal

Answer (score 1):

In the Laravel root folder chmod the storage directory to 777

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not on Laravel 4 this time, but on L5.2* I had similar issue:

I simply changed the ownership of the `storage/logs` directory to `www-data` with:

```
# chown -R www-data:www-data logs
```

> PS: This is on Ubuntu 15 and with apache.

My `logs` directory now looks like:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data   www-data 4096 jaan  23 09:39 logs/
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler this is good example for alternative to laravel3 debug bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your `app/storage/logs` there logs of `error` available. Go to filename of today's date time and you will find latest `error` in your application.

OR

Open `app/config/app.php` and change setting

```
'debug' => false,
```

To

```
'debug' => true,
```

OR

Go to `.env` file to your application and change the configuratuion

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```