# Display errors in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I know there is a similar question: [How to display errors on laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568426/how-to-display-errors-on-laravel-4)

But I can't figure out at all how to enable error displaying. what I've done:

1. In php.ini I set "display_errors = On", "error_reporting = E_ALL", "error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log"
2. In laravel's config (app.php) - debug mode
3. I looked at /app/storage/logs (no logs)
4. I looked at php_errors.log (only a simple warning here)
5. In virtual host config I specified error.log path but no info here

My code is simple:

```
public function getTest() {
    // phpinfo();
    echo $notExistingVar;
    die('123');
}
```

I cant see '123', instead I got 500 error (looked in Chrome development tools)

6. I tried multiple times "service apache2 restart" when I changed something
7. And I also tried to specify settings by ini_set directly in the code

Seems like I miss something simple, but I only see the WSOD. All the time.
Any help is greatly appreciated

**update**

At least

```
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

helped. Not in php.ini but in php script file itself

Comment: Error 500 can pretty much mean anything. At what point does that error pop up? What did you last change? What does the server error log tell you?

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error - you need to look in your apache logs or higher up. Remove sections of code until you are at a basic Laravel install (or start with a basic install to make sure it works).

Comment: error pop up in my example at echoing $notExistingVar (which doesn't exist), and I cant see nothing. In real project I used Eloquent methods with wrong syntax. If I get it correctly apache logs - those which I indicate in virtual host? (like /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite). If true, then there is no info. But I'm pretty sure PHP should output something like "var doesn't exists", no?

Comment: No. PHP defines variables automatically, so in your case that var is just empty, so the output will be blank.

Comment: Well, in any case I still get 500 error when I try to echo this variable, or, for example, when I try to use unexisting function

Comment: What entry is there in your server log?

Comment: There are no any logs (error.log is empty, app/storage/logs is empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!

I specified App::error callback and included 403, 404, and 500 error pages. I put simple text like "403" in 403.php, "404" in 404.php, but forgot to put anything in 500.php. Instead of white page I always saw something like "Server error" in Chrome, so totally forgot about this callback.

When you specify App::error then you won't get debug messages (doesn't matter debug is set to true or false in app config)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel disables display_errors in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php with

```
if ($env != 'testing') ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

This leaves you with one of the following options

1. As you suggested overwrite it later on with

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   ```
2. Disable ini_set with the [disable_functions directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)
3. Set the [Laravel environment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration) to 'testing'.