# Instagram Integration on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, instagram

I kept getting this issue after installing this package below

https://github.com/vinkla/instagram

into my Laravel 5.1 project.

[image: 2018-02-27 at 1 55 36 pm]

I followed everything in the instruction.

I am on Mac OS X, PHP 7.1, Laravel 5.1.

Did I forget something?

Comment: The provided code does not give enough info to help,

Comment: @Itisallyours : follow everything in that post, and I don't know what else to post here.

Comment: I installed a fresh 5.1.46(LTS) and the package with no issues, would you provide your laravel exact version and if this happens on all the links or specific link?

Comment: please check my below answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your `report()` method is being passed a PHP7 Throwable instead of an Exception.

Laravel 5.1 was not updated to support PHP7 Throwables until 5.1.8.

Considering the error, and the line number specified in HandleExceptions.php, it seems as if you are using a version previous to this (5.1.0 - 5.1.7).

You will need to update Laravel to at least 5.1.8 to fix this error. 5.1.8 was updated to convert Throwables to `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError` exceptions, which are then passed to the `report()` method.

Answer (score 4):

You could change `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` to not have the type declaration `Exception` and handle some logic within it to convert the Error to an Exception. It looks like this is a known issue in laravel 5.2 <= with php 7. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9650

from:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

to:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report($exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof Exception) {
        parent::report($exception);
    } else {
       // convert to exception and then parent::report.
    }

}
```

You will most likely need to do the same thing with the Handler `render` method.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: @ihue great, I'm curious to hear if that helps!

Comment: Oops! I had an exclamation in that if statement that should not have been there! @ihue, I've edited my answer to reflect how the code should look.

Comment: without `!` still return `500` error for some reaons.

Comment: do you have no code in the else statement? Can you try adding `dd($exception);` to the else? It also might have to do with render expecting an Exception as well.

Comment: No, I don't, I can try add `dd($exception);`

Comment: add the dd() still have issue.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry not sure what to say beyond that. I'll keep digging! I would suggest the following if you want to continue with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15091471/1561929

Comment: The `report` method in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` is overriding the parent `report` method. Since this is an override method, you can't change the function signature (you can't remove the type hint).

Comment: @patricus good to know! thanks for that information, I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Laravel. Do you have the last release of Laravel 5.1?

For helping debug, you might go to the [vendor/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions@handleException](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L75) and add
`dd($e)` at the first line of method.

Ex:

```
public function handleException($e)
{
    dd($e);
    //..
}
```